# How to get selected item of listview with textboxes

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, textbox

I have a Listview of Textboxes, where I need to get the selected item, but when I click at the textboxes I interact with them and the listview item isn't selected.

I have tried to find a way to make the textbox refer to the item its in.

```
<ListView MaxHeight="400" Width="663" ItemsSource="{Binding Column_2.FrontpagesList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Column_2.SelectedFrontpage, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding ProcessOrder_No, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding FinishedProduct_No, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding Colunm, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding Note, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBoxTableStyle}" Text="{Binding Week_No, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Can you mention the type of FrontpagesList ? is it List<yourCustomClass> ? if yes, please add your custom class name too..

Comment: Hey @Tvigo. Having `TextBox`es as `ListView` Children in my experience is not a good idea, When you click on a `TextBox` inside a `ListViewItem`, the Item itself does not get the focus but only `TextBox`. Instead I suggest you use `DataGrid` from `Windows Community Toolkit` and see if it is a best fit for your scenario.

Comment: @AVK What about create an answer out? DataGrid is really a good choice here since it's idea is first choose then double click to edit.

Comment: @Tvigo Do you mind to close this case if AVK create an answer out? It will also benefit other members if they see this answer.